# SpriteKit - Getting the actual size/frame of the visible area on scaled scenes .AspectFill

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, screen, resolution, visible

I have been making a game in SpriteKit and I have come into a problem when supporting all screen sizes. I attempted to resolve the problem by setting all my scenes scale modes to .AspectFill and setting a fixed size for all screens with a width of 480 and a height of 800 as shown:

> let scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 480, height: 800))

I went to add a border (an SKShapeNode) that aligns to the edges of the game scene and I found that self.frame.width and self.frame.height aren't don't give the dimensions for the device's **visible area**. After a bit of research I had discovered a lot of suggestions by using UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height and UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width. I implemented this way of getting visible screen dimensions instead and it still gave me dimensions that didn't match the actual size of the scene of which is visible to the player.

I am unsure if it has anything to do with the fact that all my scenes no matter the device's resolution have a fixed width and height and are scaled using .AspectFill. I have been stuck on the problem of supporting all screen sizes for a while now and I am unsure of how to go about it. If it helps I am using vector graphic files rather than PNG's. 
So my questions are:
Is there any quick way of supporting all screen sizes or do I have to resort to hardcoding the coordinates of every node on my scenes for every device? I can't see why this would be the solution as it seems too tedious and the code would look messy.

I am also asking about how to get a rectangle/frame that gives the dimensions of the scenes visible area on a device after the scene has been scaled?

I am sorry if either of my questions have been asked before but every answer I find either doesn't solve my problem specifically or seems too messy to write. I think I have given enough information towards the problem but if I haven't please ask me for the required information.

Thank you so much and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how Aspect Fill works:

The dimensions of your scene will always remain the same, so if you say your scene is 480 points by 800 points,  it will always remain that way regardless of device.

What then happens is it will scale the scene starting from the center of the `SKView` until it fills the farthest walls.

This will in turn crop your scene.

So when designing your game across the different aspect ratios, you will need to design your game to handle cropping.

Now in your particular case, You will need to figure out what the aspect ratio is for the device, and work off the difference from the scene aspect.

E.G.  Your scene is 3x5, device is 9x16,  This means your device is going to grow to become 9.6x16 to fill up to the size of your 9x16 device.  We get this because our height has more distance than our width, so we need to do 3/5 = a/16, 3*16 = a * 5, (3*16)/5 = a so a = 9.6.

This means you have .6 of cropping to your scene on the width,  .3 on both edges.

Now you are going to ask,  How does the .3 relate to the various screen sizes.

Well we need to figure out what percentage .3 is of 9.6.  We do that with division,  .3/9.6 = .03125 or 3.125%;  This means we need to push our border in 3.125% in the scene's width, which is 15 points. That means .03125 * 480 = 15. Your borders should then start at 15 width and at 465.

Pseudo Code:

```
let newSceneWidth = (scene.width * view.height) / (scene.height)
let sceneDifference = (newSceneWidth - view.Width)/2
let diffPercentage = sceneDifference / (newSceneWidth)

let leftEdge = diffPercentage * scene.width;
let rightEdge = scene.width - (diffPercentage * scene.width);
```

Now if there is more distance to scale in the height than the width, you would have to swap the width and height variables.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am going to try this!! Do you think the way I am programming the game scenes is the best way though? Or would you suggest programming the scenes layout (positioning etc) in a different way rather than a scaleMode?

Comment: The way I do most of my games, is I have my scene at 9x16 ratio, then I just do not draw anything important in the areas that get cropped off.  For things like a HUD,  I shift based on the math I showed you, or I do my hud as UIView components, depending on the game

Comment: Thankfully with how small retina pixels are,  it is really hard to tell scaling artifacts, but if you do end up seeing them, then you would need to rework your code somehow obviously

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have one question sorry if it is stupid but where did you get the 4x3 from? I understand the 9x16 ratio it is just that one!! Sorry :D

Comment: 4x3?  What are you referring to

Comment: 3x5* sorry haha!! My bad

Comment: So keep the scaling at .AspectFill and position HUD elements based on the visible screen size as shown in your answer? And do you think I should consider changing my aspect ratio from a 3x5 to a 9x16? What would be the benefits if so?

Comment: The benefit is most devices are 9x16 (iphone 5 and on). The only devices not 9x16 would be iphone 4s and your ipads

Comment: Oh sweet!! Thank you so much I will attempt the development with this method!! :D

Comment: It doesn't solve every problem,  but it does work well and is easy to design for

Comment: If I were you,  make your scene size 320x568,  the retina graphics will work themselves in

Comment: Will do!! What problems are still known to frequently come up for you that it doesn't solve? Just so I could be aware of them

Comment: You may not want different aspects to show more than others

Comment: No easy answer,  would depend on the game.  You need to utilize the entire screen some how,  whether it be black bars or special HUDs based on aspect,  who knows

Comment: Okay!! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I have finally had the time to work on the game and I have implemented trying the exact same code you have suggested and returned it as a CGRect to then make a border for the screen. For some reason when I display the border with the scene's anchorpoint being (0, 0) it only shows along the right and bottom of the screen... Would you know why this is?

Comment: because you set the anchor point at 0,0, you don't want to touch anchor point, you want it centered

Comment: What would you recommend I set the anchor point to of the scene? I am using an SKShapeNode for the border that matches the CGRect and as far as I know SKShapeNodes do not have anchor points... :/

Comment: why do you even need to set anchor points, i would leave them alone

Comment: Yeah I have... I thought I changed the scene's anchor point but I didn't... So I printed the anchor point and it is (0,0)

Comment: if you did my code, you need to make sure it is doing floating point division, not integer,  cast all the variables to float

Comment: They are :/ This is weird why it isn't working because I have gone over the math multiple times and tried so many things

Comment: only other thing i can think of is you are doing it before the view resizes

Comment: The function is called in the GameScene didMoveToView

Comment: means nothing,  depends on when you present it to the view, need to preset at a point where view is resized in view controller,  try overriding willMoveToWindow,  I can't test rigt now but that is where I am doing it

Comment: in your view controller

Comment: There is no willMoveToWindow... :(

Comment: I am and it is saying it doesn't exist :(

Comment: sorry I overrode the view to get that,  for the view controller you need to do it at viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Do I move all of my viewDidLoad stuff into it? And when does it get called?

Comment: just present the scene then

Comment: that gets called after the constraints are applied

Comment: Well check to make sure all your numbers are coming out correct mathematically

Comment: I will try that!! Sorry for all the questions

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the answers and a special thanks to KnightOfDragon who helped me come to a workaround for my problem. What I have done is created a function that produces a CGRect which takes in consideration the dimensions of a device as well as its predetermined aspect ratio of a scene. This can be used as a boundary and makes it easier for relative positioning of nodes in a scene so that they will be visible for all devices. Again a special thanks to KnightOfDragon who answered with the basis of the code for the solution and without them it would have been difficult and I would't be able to share this overall solution. Here is the final code in Swift:

```
//Returns a CGRect that has the dimensions and position for any device with respect to any specified scene. This will result in a boundary that can be utilised for positioning nodes on a scene so that they are always visible
func getVisibleScreen(var sceneWidth: Float, var sceneHeight: Float, viewWidth: Float, viewHeight: Float) -> CGRect {
    var x: Float = 0
    var y: Float = 0

    let deviceAspectRatio = viewWidth/viewHeight
    let sceneAspectRatio = sceneWidth/sceneHeight

    //If the the device's aspect ratio is smaller than the aspect ratio of the preset scene dimensions, then that would mean that the visible width will need to be calculated
    //as the scene's height has been scaled to match the height of the device's screen. To keep the aspect ratio of the scene this will mean that the width of the scene will extend
    //out from what is visible. 
    //The opposite will happen in the device's aspect ratio is larger.
    if deviceAspectRatio < sceneAspectRatio {
        let newSceneWidth: Float = (sceneWidth * viewHeight) / sceneHeight
        let sceneWidthDifference: Float = (newSceneWidth - viewWidth)/2
        let diffPercentageWidth: Float = sceneWidthDifference / (newSceneWidth)

        //Increase the x-offset by what isn't visible from the lrft of the scene
        x = diffPercentageWidth * sceneWidth
        //Multipled by 2 because the diffPercentageHeight is only accounts for one side(e.g right or left) not both
        sceneWidth = sceneWidth - (diffPercentageWidth * 2 * sceneWidth)
    } else {
        let newSceneHeight: Float = (sceneHeight * viewWidth) / sceneWidth
        let sceneHeightDifference: Float = (newSceneHeight - viewHeight)/2
        let diffPercentageHeight: Float = fabs(sceneHeightDifference / (newSceneHeight))

        //Increase the y-offset by what isn't visible from the bottom of the scene
        y = diffPercentageHeight * sceneHeight
        //Multipled by 2 because the diffPercentageHeight is only accounts for one side(e.g top or bottom) not both
        sceneHeight = sceneHeight - (diffPercentageHeight * 2 * sceneHeight)
    }

    let visibleScreenOffset = CGRect(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), width: CGFloat(sceneWidth), height: CGFloat(sceneHeight))
    return visibleScreenOffset
}
```

Comment: This is exact I searched for. This func gives me the area what on a device is    
shown from a fixed sized scene from a game; i.e. a SpriteKit Scene of 1536x2048  shown on iPhone 6 width view of 375x667 results
(192.287872314453, 0.0, 1151.42431640625, 2048.0)
This means a Rect of 1152x2048 is shown on portrait mode and 192 points on left and right are cropped.

Comment: I didn't downvote this and it might a be a bit too late to comment but this code mutates parameters that are passed is no longer valid swift code.

Comment: This is soooo helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for this! One thing to note for people who uses camera node: this solution only assumes the camera scale is default 1.0. If you have different camera scale, you need to multiply that value into this calculation.

Answer (score 8):

There is actually a very simple way to do this. The function `convertPoint(fromView:)` on SKScene allows a point to be converted from its containing SKView's coordinate system into scene space coordinates. You can therefore take the view's origin and a point equal to its farthest extent, convert them both into the scene's coordinate space, and measure the difference like so:

```
extension SKScene {
    func viewSizeInLocalCoordinates() -> CGSize {
        let reference = CGPoint(x: view!.bounds.maxX, y: view!.bounds.maxY)
        let bottomLeft = convertPoint(fromView: .zero)
        let topRight = convertPoint(fromView: reference)
        let d = topRight - bottomLeft
        return CGSize(width: d.x, height: d.y)
    }
}
```

(Note that I am also using an extension of `CGPoint` which allows me to perform addition and subtraction using points directly. See below. Also note that it is only safe to call this function after the scene has been presented; I'm being a bit lazy by force-unwrapping `view`, which will be `nil` if the scene is not being displayed yet.)

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func +(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }
    static func -(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
}
```

**Important:** this assumes that the scene has no camera node assigned, or that the camera node's scale is 1:1. If you add your own camera node and allow it to be scaled in order to create a zoom effect, use the code below instead. Also keep in mind that nodes attached to the camera node itself do not scale with the rest of the scene. I've allowed for this in my code here by providing `ignoreCameraScale`. Pass true to this parameter if the measurements relate to HUD elements that move and scale with the camera.

```
extension SKScene {
    func viewSizeInLocalCoordinates(ignoreCameraScale: Bool = false) -> CGSize {
        let reference = CGPoint(x: view!.bounds.maxX, y: view!.bounds.maxY)
        var bottomLeft = convertPoint(fromView: .zero)
        var topRight = convertPoint(fromView: reference)

        if ignoreCameraScale, let camera = camera {
            bottomLeft = camera.convert(bottomLeft, from: self)
            topRight = camera.convert(topRight, from: self)
        }

        let d = topRight - bottomLeft
        return CGSize(width: d.x, height: -d.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why:

```
struct Constants {
    static let vcHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    static let vcWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
}
```

doesn't give the proper bounds.
But i don't know why you would want to use .aspectFill for getting the right sizes.
When i made my game i used this

```
let position.x = vcHeight/3   //to putting him on a third of the screen for all iPhone's
```

This can also be use for getting the proper sizes.
I have no knowledge on vector graphics so i can't help you further.

Comment: Thank you!! I have used aspectFill for scaling the entire scene and I think that might be why it doesn't give the proper bounds... I have been using aspectFill as a scale mode because of consistent positioning on all screens be it iPad or iPhone because of problems with my first mobile game... I am still relatively new however and not quite sure what the best way to solve the problem is so is this a better way do you think than scaling?

Comment: you should not be positioning your guy based on percentage unless you do ALL of your math based on percentage,  that means that the speed the player moves have to be percentage based, otherwise you get a different experience across devices

Comment: You should do that but this is the more easy approach

Comment: not saying it is wrong, just saying that all math would have to be percentage based.  E.G.  you can't say sprite.moveToX(10,y:10,duration:1), you would have to do sprite.moveToX(%,y:%,duration:1), and sprite.velocity = 1 would have to be sprite.velocity = %

Comment: I know it is gone be a lot of work. But if you want it only of iPhone or iPad you could leave some thing's out because it will be less notice able.

Comment: That is definitely not true anymore,  iPhones have 4 different screen sizes to worry about,  iPad only has 1, so you may as well just plan around all 5 sizes